# Sylvester function in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to run a code in Octave written basically for Matlab.

One of the functions from this code file named - Sylvester(A,B,C) which is documented in Octave-forge as available is failing with following error.

```
error: 'sylvester' undefined near line 14 column 9
```

The octave version that I am using is 3.8.2.

I am new to Octave.
Can someone suggest what extra I need to do in Octave so as to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update Octave. The function [`sylvester`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Functions-of-a-Matrix.html#index-sylvester) was only added in [Octave 4.0.0](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/1c96b44feb7a/NEWS#l762).

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot.. also when I tried to use lyap(A,B,C) function, it gives me same problem. So is this function also part of version 4.0.0? Why there are 2 versions of sylvester function? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @PallaviJog the function `lyap` is not in Octave, it is part of the control package.

Answer (score 0):

In Octave, for Sylvester function, they have used `lyap(A,B,C)` function for solving

> AX+XB+C=0

type of optimization function.

Though, the original sylvester function is

> AX+XB=C

I am not sure how they call both the functions as sylvester form.